# CSS: background-color linear-gradient does not work for SVG url

Tags: html, css

This is my css code and work fine:

```
display: inline-block;
background-color: #000;
mask-image: url('../public/svg/home.svg');
```

My icon color is black.

I want to use gradient like below:

```
display: inline-block;
background-color: linear-gradient(180deg, #000, #fff);
mask-image: url('../public/svg/home.svg');
```

But does not work for me

Comment: `linear-gradient` is an `<image>`, it can't be used for `background-color`, use `background-image` instead.